# Looping an "If..And...Then..." statement with automated email in VBA MS Excel

Tags: vba, excel, email, loops

I'm very new to coding on any platform and have been working hard to get this code up and running. I have a conditional statement that is attached to an automatic email function that sends an email if the condition is met. This portion of the code works, but only for the row of the spreadsheet the code is specific to (row 2). I need it to cycle through all available rows and create a specific email for each row where the condition is met. Here is the code I have

```
Sub macro1() 'prelim dictation

Set cdomsg = CreateObject("CDO.message")
With cdomsg.Configuration.Fields
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'NTLM method
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smptserverport") = 587
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "imcool@gmail.com"
 .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "imcoolpasscode"
 .Update
    End With

    If Cells(2, 2) + 5 <= Cells(2, 17) And Cells(2, 4) = "INCOMPLETE" Then
With cdomsg
.To = "danielcarnam@yahoo.com"
.From = "danielcarnam@gmail.com"
.Subject = "Work to be done"
.TextBody = Cells(2, 1) & Space(3) & Cells(1, 3)
.Send
End With
Set cdomsg = Nothing
Else
End If
End Sub



   A         B     C(x1)     D        E(x2)        F         ............. Q
 1  Patient  Date       "Incomplete"       "Incomplete"             =TODAY()
 2  John Doe 1/25       "Incomplete"       "Incomplete"
 3  Jane Doe 1/30       "Incomplete"       "Incomplete"
.
.
```

Above is an example of my spreadsheet.
When the portion of the report is completed I enter that date into column "C" and column "D" changes to "complete". Essentially what my code says is, If todays date is within 5 days of date of service (B2), and column D is "incomplete", Then send an email, where the text body is the patients name and the title of column D ("x1") (Cells 1,3). The code will have 10+ sections for each patient (Expanding out similar to columns E and F) and at least 30 patients per month. I need a code that loops through the patients to the end of the list and sends a correlating email (patients name and specific section of the report thats delayed (x1,x2...) when conditions are met. 
So far i have written three sperate modules for each section (x1,x2,x3) and a master to run them all at once. a secondary question i would like to ask is if i can place them all in one module so that i dont crash the computer or have to run the code for an hour to get results. 
I apologize for the length of my query, but i couldnt figure out how to word it more briefly. Any help is hugely appreciated and ill of course be happy to answer any questions you may have. Thanks a million. 
-Dan

Comment: Google `for` loop and `lastrow`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create variables for the rows (and columns if needed) and then a loop to process.

```
dim row as integer
row = 2
while cells(row, 1) <> ""
    INSERT YOUR CODE HERE, REPLACE HARD CODED ROW #S WITH VARIABLE "row"
    e.g. if cells(row, 2) + 5...
    row = row + 1
wend
```

Comment: tried this and it gave me an run time error 91 and highlighted the row                     "  .To = "dan***@yahoo.com"   "   Strangely the first time i run the code it will send an email, as it did before the addition (only running the first row) but will give the error and will not send another email the next time i run the code without restarting vba.  tried googling the issue, but admittedly dont really know what im doing. most of this code is copy paste from other folks. Appreciate the help up to this point and any other help you can offer.   Thanks

Comment: Update your question with the code as it exists now. An error 91 indicates cdomsg is no longer defined. You can try putting the line "Set cdomsg = nothing" outside the loop and see if that solves it.

Comment: Not sure what happened, but left the cdomsg in the loop and it ran no hiccups, looped like a hot wheel track :) THanks a million for the help!! I can update the working code if any one wants let me know